Jest mock of service keeps giving empty data
I am trying to make a unit test for testing my states of my component but keep getting errors.
First i got textdecoder is not defined. I fixed that by adding a jest config:
module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@mocks/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/Tests/Units/$1"
    }
};

Now i am mocking my service class to test if it gets exercises from my component, but it keeps getting empty and can't find a solution.
This is my component:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { readAllExercisesFromFirestore } from '../../Services/fireBaseExerciseService';
import FirebaseImageDisplay from "../readImageFromImageName";
import "../../Styling/Exercise/ExerciseItem.css";

function ExerciseItem({ exercise }) {
    return (
        <li className="listWithItems">
            <div className="listContainerExercise">
                <div className="exercisePhoto">
                    <FirebaseImageDisplay imageName={exercise.photoName} path="exercise/" />
                </div>
                <h2>{exercise.Name}</h2>
                <p>{exercise.Description}</p>
                <p className="levelText">{exercise.Level}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
}

function ExerciseList() {
    const [exercises, setExercises] = useState([]);
    const [filteredExercises, setFilteredExercises] = useState([]);
    const [selectedMuscleGroup, setSelectedMuscleGroup] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchExercises() {
            try {
                const allExercises = await readAllExercisesFromFirestore();
                setExercises(allExercises);
                setFilteredExercises(allExercises);
            } catch (error) {
                setError('Er is een fout opgetreden bij het ophalen van de oefeningen.');
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        }

        fetchExercises();
    }, []);

    const handleFilterChange = (e) => {
        const selectedGroup = e.target.value;
        setSelectedMuscleGroup(selectedGroup);

        if (selectedGroup === '') {
            setFilteredExercises(exercises);
        } else {
            const filtered = exercises.filter(exercise => exercise.MuscleGroup === selectedGroup);
            setFilteredExercises(filtered);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <select className="muscleGroupFilter" value={selectedMuscleGroup} onChange={handleFilterChange}>
                    <option value="">Alle</option>
                    <option value="Abs">Buikspieren</option>
                    <option value="Legs">Benen</option>
                    <option value="Shoulder">Schouders</option>
                    <option value="Arms">Armen</option>
                    <option value="Chest">Borst</option>
                    <option value="Back">Rug</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            {loading ? (
                <p>Laden...</p>
            ) : error ? (
                <p>{error}</p>
            ) : (
                <ul className="listOfAllExercises">
                    {filteredExercises.map(exercise => (
                        <ExerciseItem key={exercise.id} exercise={exercise} />
                    ))}
                </ul>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ExerciseList;

This is my test:
import React from 'react';
import { render, waitFor, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import ExerciseList from '../../../Components/Exercise/ExerciseList';
import { readAllExercisesFromFirestore } from '../../../Services/fireBaseExerciseService';

import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'util';
Object.assign(global, { TextEncoder, TextDecoder });

// Mock the API call
jest.mock('../../../Services/fireBaseExerciseService');

// Mock data
const mockExercises = [
    { id: 1, MuscleGroup: 'Abs', Name: 'Exercise 1', Description: 'Description 1', Level: 'Beginner', photoName: 'exercise1.jpg' },
    { id: 2, MuscleGroup: 'Legs', Name: 'Exercise 2', Description: 'Description 2', Level: 'Intermediate', photoName: 'exercise2.jpg' },
    // Add more mock exercises as needed
];

// Set mock implementation for the API call
readAllExercisesFromFirestore.mockResolvedValue(mockExercises);

describe('ExerciseList component', () => {
    it('fetches and displays exercises correctly', async () => {
        render(<ExerciseList />);

        // Wait for the component to fetch and render exercises
        await waitFor(() => {
            // Check if all exercises are rendered
            mockExercises.forEach(exercise => {
                expect(screen.getByText(exercise.Name)).toBeInTheDocument();
                expect(screen.getByText(exercise.Description)).toBeInTheDocument();
                expect(screen.getByText(exercise.Level)).toBeInTheDocument();
            });
        });
    });

    // Add more test cases as needed
});


